# Does internet explorer support bot deployed using backchannel?

Tags: internet-explorer, botframework

I've deployed a bot written in c# using [backchannel](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat). It works fine on all the browsers including chrome, edge and mozilla firefox except for internet explorer. It just does not open. Is there a solution for this ?

This is the backchannel html code which I run.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Bot Chat</title>
  <link href="botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <style>
    .wc-chatview-panel {
        width: 420px;
        height: 500px;
        position: relative; 
    }
    .h2{
        font-family: Segoe UI;
    }
    .bottomcorner{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:5px;
        right:0
    }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body onload="postLoadMessage()">
   <div id="BotChatGoesHere" class="bottomcorner"> <!-- "wc-narrow"></div>-->
      <script src="botchat.js"></script>
      <script>

        var params = BotChat.queryParams(location.search);
        var user = { id: userid };
        var bot = {
            id: bot,
        };

        window['botchatDebug'] = params['debug'] && params['debug'] === "true";

        var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
            secret: secretkey,
            token: params['t'],
            domain: params['domain'],
            webSocket: params['webSocket'] && params['webSocket'] === "true" 
        });

        BotChat.App({
            botConnection: botConnection,
            user: user,
            bot: bot
        }, document.getElementById("BotChatGoesHere"));

        botConnection.activity$
            .filter(activity => activity.type === "event" && activity.name === "changeBackground")
            .subscribe(activity => changeBackgroundColor(activity.value))
        const changeBackgroundColor = (newColor) => {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
        }

        const postLoadMessage = () => {
            botConnection
                .postActivity({type: "event", value: "" , from: {id: "me" }, name: "PageLoaded"})
                .subscribe(id => console.log("success"));
        }
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any JavaScript error in the browser's console?

Comment: @EzequielJadib nope. No error. And i think if there was an error then wouldn't it have not shown in other browsers too?

Comment: @nupurkamble internet explorer is not like other browsers..

Comment: Not necessarily, there could be features used not supported by IE. Can you double check if any error appears?

Comment: Yes it says syntax error when it reaches  "const postLoadMessage = () => {" part

Comment: I have the same issue and no error in the console. Have you managed to fix this?

Comment: @SmartDev no I havent been able to solve it. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @nupurkamble  Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change:

```
.subscribe(id => console.log("success"));
```

with:

```
.subscribe(function (id) { console.log("success"); });
```

and everything will be OK in IE also.

In fact, change all the *arrow functions* (=>):

```
foo => ...
```

with

```
function(foo) { ... }
```

because these functions are part of ECMAScript 6 which is not supported in IE11.
See more about this at: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6.